# Flutter VLC Player with options

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, vlc, flutter-video-player

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleVideoState createState() => _ExampleVideoState();
}

class _ExampleVideoState extends State<Home> {

  final VlcPlayerController controller = new VlcPlayerController.network(url);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 40,
            child: new VlcPlayer(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
             options : VlcPlayeroptions(),
                controller: controller,
                placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

this is my example where video is playing good, but i need to add options to it like play and pause, "options" is not working

i need to add play and pause button on vlc player in flutter app

Comment: please dont forget to also vote up my answer and maybe edit your question if you want to add your solution, better than in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleVideoState createState() => _ExampleVideoState();
}

class _ExampleVideoState extends State<Home> {
 late bool _isplaying = true;
  final VlcPlayerController controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
    "url",
    hwAcc: HwAcc.auto,
    options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
  );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:  Column(children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 225,
            child: VlcPlayer(
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              controller: controller,
              placeholder: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              if (_isplaying)
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.pause();
                    setState(() {
                      _isplaying = false;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.play_arrow,
                    size: 50,
                    
                  ),
                )
              else
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isplaying = true;
                      controller.play();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.pause,
                    size: 50,
                    
                  ),
                ),
            ]),
          ),]
    );
  }
}
```

This is how i get it work done

Answer (score 1):

Add a widget that sends play/pause through the controller class. Check out the other available methods too for the [VlcPlayerController](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_vlc_player/latest/flutter_vlc_player/VlcPlayerController-class.html) class.

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () => controller.pause(),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
            label: const Text('Pause'))
```